# Get latest twitter status WITHOUT authentication?

Tags: php, twitter

so a few days ago Twitter sadly stopped supporting their 1.0 API. Now they have a new 1.1 API in place and suddenly they require you to authenticate (create an app, create keys, download oauth.php, download twitteroauth.php, etc...) for everything (including grabbing the latest status) and that is just... URGH! NO THANKS!

I just want to have a little .php script that gets the latest status of a user. There must be an easy way to achieve this without authenticating.

Does anyone have an idea?

**EDIT:** Hello fellow Googler. I have found a solution myself and posted it below. Make sure to check it out.

Comment: Why is it a problem to authenticate?

Comment: @crush because you shouldn't have to authenticate for something that is public anyway?

Comment: It is up to Twitter to decide how you should or shouldn't be able to access their services, isn't it? Authentication means they can ban abusive users.

Comment: @crush Surely they can do that, but developers will always find a way around if something is openly accessible for anyone.

It doesn't make any sense, forcing you to create an app (and much more, see my OP) just for something trivial. If you can view the tweets of a person without being logged in on any computer, why should a bot not be able to do the same?

I'm one of the first users asking this question and I guarantuee you, I will find a solution, post it in the OP and within days thousands of people googling exact the same problem will bypass Twitter's stupid new rules using this post.

Comment: That's your prerogative. You could always parse HTTP Requests to the public Twitter pages, but if you get a lot of hits, they will probably IP ban you. Implementing OAuth is a fairly trivial thing in comparison.

Comment: No, a trivial thing is the solution I'm working on. It's like three lines of code. I'll edit my OP in a few minutes.

Comment: /me *whistles* http://y.ahoo.it/yUb5z :)

Comment: @AnthonySterling How long before Twitter bans that YQL proxies authentication credentials? =]

Comment: @crush I'd say it will happen after they have deprecated their 1.1 API.

Comment: @JonasKaufmann It will happen after an immense amount of traffic starts coming from a single user - that YQL proxy. That's the entire purpose of authentication - so they can track this. Trying to get around the rules will only get you in trouble. Just do it the right way. You don't have to use the OAuth library to authenticate with OAuth. All you need is to understand how to send headers. Twitter has just provided those things so that you can more easily implement it.

Comment: @crush Thanks for the effort, but I just don't want to do all that additional work. And I think I'm not the only one out there who doesn't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a quick and dirty fix using **http://www.twitter-rss.com/** - I expect this solution to run a while before it shuts down. If it does not work anymore, make sure to message me and I'll create my own Twitter -> RSS service for you guys to use.

Alright, now here's the code on how to get the latest twitter status without having to use their API, create an App or all that other *stuff*.

```
function GetTwitterStatus($username){
    $url = "http://www.twitter-rss.com/user_timeline.php?screen_name=".$username;
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("Could not connect.");
    $tweet = (string) $xml->channel->item[0]->title;
    $tweet = substr_replace($tweet, "", 0, strlen($username.": "));
    return $tweet;
}

echo GetTwitterStatus("Twitter");
```

Comment: A decent stop gap solution. You could use a similar method to extract it from HTTP/HTML requests. They are basically the same thing, just different formats.

Answer (score 2):

Read here:

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/changes-coming-to-twitter-api

> For example, there are many applications that are *pulling data from
>   the Twitter API at very high rates (scraping, bots, etc.)* where we
>   only know the IP address of the applications. **To prevent malicious use
>   of the Twitter API** and gain an understanding of what types of
>   applications are accessing the API in order to evolve it to meet the
>   needs of developers, it's important to have visibility into the
>   activity on the Twitter API and the applications using the platform.
>
> **In version 1.1, we will require every request to the API to be authenticated**. For developers who are already using OAuth when
>   making API requests, all of your authentication tokens will transition
>   seamlessly from v1.0 to v1.1. If your application is currently using
>   the Twitter API without using OAuth, you will need to update your
>   application before March 2013. There's more information about the
>   timing of the transition from v1.0 to v1.1 below.

They did this to prevent spammers from eating up Twitter's bandwidth. So sorry mate, you'll have to conform as well.

Comment: So, they gave notice 7 months in advance? Seems like plenty of notice.